# How can I create a simple internationalization (i18n) example in Kohana v3.0.6.2?

Tags: internationalization, kohana

I've been trying to make i18n work: Just to display a string with 2 different languages. I followed [this tutorial](http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/Kohana-2.4-I18N-internationalization-and-localization-Library), but I think the author is not using Kohana 3.

It basically consist on creating a langauge file (`pl.php`) file in the `i18n` folder, and add the following:

```
<?php

$translations['Good Morning'] = 'Magandang Umaga';
```

Then changing the locale to `pl`.

and finally the output in the view file:

```
<?php echo __('Good Morning'); // would produce 'Good Morning' ?>
```

I really got lost in the tutorial.

Can anyone give me a small example of using internationalization (i18n) in Kohana v3.0.6.2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how your i18n/pl.php file should look like:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

return array(
    'Good Morning' => 'Magandang Umaga',
);
```

you can't copy everything that you see from a ko2 tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the key from the translations file. i.e.

```
<?php echo __('good_morning'); // would produce 'Magandang Umaga' if the locale was 'pl' ?>
```

but you can also use real words as the key, so in your pl.php file you would have:

```
$translations['Good Morning'] = 'Magandang Umaga';
```

and then you can use:

```
<?php echo __('Good Morning'); // would produce 'Magandang Umaga' if the locale was 'pl' ?>
```

in your view.